# MySQL How to select attribute that have spaces in between them via the 'new' command inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have an attribute called Maximum Seats in my Room Table but I do not know how to select/access it while accessing it through a trigger on AFTER INSERT.

```
ROOMS (RoomID, Maximum Seats)
Primary Key: RoomID

ROOM OCCUPANCY (RoomID, Seat Number)
Primary Key: RoomID
Foreign Key: RoomID References Rooms(RoomID)
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_populate AFTER INSERT ON rooms
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT;
    SET count = 1;
    WHILE count < new.Maximum_Seats do
    INSERT INTO `room occupancy` (`RoomID`, `Seat Number`) VALUES (new.RoomID, count);
    END WHILE;
END
```

In the event that changing the attribute name is not an option, how can I select `new.'Maximum Seats'` or `new.Maximum_Seats` or `new.MaximumSeats`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new.`Maximum Seats`
```

Just like in your insert, but qualified by new.